# Matlab string concatenation behavior with different data types

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab 2018b on Windows 10. I understand that the Matlab string concatenation needs input arguments under concatenation to be a character array, a cell array of character vectors, or a string array as mentioned in https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html. Based on this i was expecting an error while trying to do the following:

```
[1, 'some_string']
```

or

```
strcat(1, 'some_string')
```

But i am not getting any error message. Instead getting output as displayed in the snapshot below:

[image]

Based on below, looks like automatic type conversion is taking place for 1 from `double` to `char` but seems something in getting wrong in the process resulting in 1 being replaced with a junk char. Any insight in to this please?

```
x = strcat(1, 'some_string');
class(x(1))

ans =

    'char'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab is treating the `1` as an ascii code, corresponding to the `start of heading` character which is being displayed as the square you see.

It is more obvious what Matlab is doing if you e.g. do `strcat(65, 'some_string')`, which returns `Asome_string` as the ascii code 65 corresponds to a capital `A`.